# Homebrew CPU RAM

Tags: cpu, eeprom, ram, homebrew-cpu

I’m trying to build a CPU out of TTL logic chips.  I’ve just about got everything finished, however, I’m still working on the RAM.  I don’t have any suitable RAM chips I can use, however, I do have a couple of these EEPROM chips available (link.)  Can I use these?  I probably won’t need to write too much to it, and the CPU will operate at very low frequencies.  It is going to be a very basic CPU, in fact, I’ll probably just be happy if I can get the thing to count.  I can’t think of any reason why these won’t work.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002213B.pdf

Comment: it usually won't work because the controller in the eeprom itself typically speaks a serially transported command language, which really means you need a working CPU just to talk to it. But it depends on the EEPROM type – I can imagine some simply actually having address lines. **What EEPROM type are we talking about? Link to a datasheet!** However, EEPROMs really typically make it significantly more complex to read and write them than RAM ICs, so I doubt you're doing yourself any favor here.

Comment: Cool, thanks .  I’ll add a data sheet now...

Comment: That's an I²C EEPROM – an I²C bus controller able to read arbitrary addresses is quite likely more complex than your whole CPU at this point…

Comment: Get some RAM or else FeRAM chips. It will simplify things a lot.

Comment: An idea to consider is that at slow clock rates you could use an MCU and its software as your memory.  It sounds silly, but a key advantage is that if you let it stop the CPU and it has a serial or USB interface, then you can get in to pre-load, examine, or change things, which is a *huge* advantage over the tools typically available to a hobbyist trying to bootstrap a TTL computer in the era of TTL.

Comment: i might have some old RAM chips somewhere - where are you based?

Answer (score 5):

That's an I²C EEPROM – an I²C bus controller able to read arbitrary addresses is quite likely more complex than your whole CPU at this point.

So, get yourself a simple static RAM IC with separate data and address buses.

Comment: In particular, a CMOS static RAM in a 2k x 8 bits configuration used to be available from a large number of manufacturers, and would be perfect for this application. Look for part numbers containing "2016" or "6116". 8k x 8 bits was also quite common -- look for "6264".

Comment: The 62256 (62C256) is also quite commonly available from even the smaller suppliers.